# Laravel get id with whereHas relation

Tags: laravel

I'm trying get the id of answer id that has relation with question by whereHas

```
    $answers = Question::whereHas('answers',function($q) use($key){
        return $q->where('comment','LIKE','%'.$key.'%')->with('answers.id');
    })->limit(50)->get();
```

I put `->with('answers.id');` for explain idea more ,so how can i get the id of answer ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Project::with(['answers', 'answers.id'])
   ->whereHas('answers', function($q) use($key) {
       return $q->where('comment','LIKE','%'.$key.'%') 
   })->limit(50)
   ->get();
```

Comment: Call to undefined relationship [id] on model [App\Answer]. but when remove `answers.id` it's work but get all answer data

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `->select()`?

```
$answers = Question::whereHas('answers',function($q) use($key){
    return $q->where('comment','LIKE','%'.$key.'%')->select('id');
})->limit(50)->get();
```